# Sharepoint 2007 core.css

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Sharepoint 2007:
Core.css file is located in the 12 Folder:
12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES

but my question is : is this file shared for all webapplications on sharepoint server?

I think it is not because when I make changes in the core.css, only one of the applications showed the changes, so where is the others core.css files located?

I made search in my c driver I find only one core.css!!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This file is shared by all Web Applications. What you experience is most likely a result of aggressive client side web browser caching. Try clearing your browsers cache and refresh the page.

Having said that...
This is not the way you are supposed to customize SharePoint. You should never touch the OOB files in the 12 hive. Next time you apply an update or service pack all of your changes are gone. Also, by touching the OOB files, you automatically lose all support from Microsoft.

Rather, you should either a) develop a SharePoint feature that publish a custom master page with your CSS changes or b) do master page changes using SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 0):

Core.css is always shared by all web applications.

AS magnus said what u have seen is due to the browser caching or somehthing like that. delete the browser cache or Restart the browser and then try again..

May this help you

Thanks